# Update másivo a tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, db2

Trabajando con Tablas HTML, me topé con un pequeño problema, bien, tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena dinámicamente con python y Flask:

```
 <div class="container table table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="data-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Hostname</th>
                    <th>Bay</th>
                    <th>Slot</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {% for row in result %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{row ['HOSTNAME']}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{row ['BAY']}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{row ['RACK']}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{row ['DESCRIPTION']}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                        <button type="button" class="boton btn btn-light button-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLong">
                         </button>

                     </td>

                </tr>

                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

obteniendo como resultado la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es poder editar cada una de las columnas de la tabla, cosa que ya hice, el problema que no he podido solucionar o no encuentro respesta, es: como puedo hacer un update masivo a la tabla, es decir, seleccionar con un check las columnas que quiero actualizar, y poderlas actualizar todas de una sola vez.

Hasta ahora, solo puedo editar columna por columna de la siguiente manera; al dar clic en el botón obtengo los valores de la columna en una ventana modal: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el update lo hago con la siguiente función de python:

```
    bay= request.form['Bay']
    rack= request.form['Rack']
    status= request.form['Status']
    user= request.form['User']
    comment= request.form['Comment']
    sql="UPDATE CMGT.CELLS SET ID_STATUS ="+str(status)+" WHERE 
    HOSTNAME='"+hostname.strip()+"';"  
    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,sql)
```

Y automaticamente mis datos se actualizan.

Comment: Como diferencias que columnas vas a actualizar y lo otro seria que agregues el código de como harías el servicio para actualizar los datos de la tabla.

Comment: No es tanto diferenciar, por ejemplo, lo que ahora tengo ya, es que al dar clic en el  boton edit obtengo los valores de la columna en una ventana modal y los actualizo mediante una llamada POST de Ajax, los mando a python y con python hago el update a la base con los datos obtenidos.  

Tenía pensado algo como que, cada que dé clic en el check, me guarde esos valores en algún array y al final lanzarlos todos en una consulta. Lo de diferenciar, no sé a que exactamente te refieres @bercklynCarlosviza

Comment: Puedes agregar tu ejemplo de como guardas la información con un update  unico.

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice.

Comment: Creo que tal como lo estas haciendo esta bien ya que si haces que se mande un array de objetos si estos fueran muchos  tu consulta se demoraría demasiado como para que un usuario espere a que se complete. Por orto lado si es lo que buscas hacer entonces te puedo brindar la sintaxis de como se harria según mi criterio. Por ultimo puedes añadir un ejemplo de como mandas un objeto a tu servicio python.